# SQL Join three tables 17

Tags: sql, inner-join

TBL1 (Product) has ProductNo(PK), suburb, Foreign key (storeNo, staffNo)

TBL2 (Store) has storeNo(PK), suburb

TBL3 (Staff) has staffNo(PK), Foreign key (storeNo)

```
SELECT Product.productNo, Product.suburb, Store.suburb, (SELECT Store.suburb
    FROM Store, Staff
    WHERE Staff.storeNo = Store.storeNo)
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Store ON Product.storeNo = Store.StoreNo
INNER JOIN Staff ON Product.staffNo = Staff.staffNo AND Store.storeNo = Staff.storeNo
```

Hello, so I have 3 tables here store, staff and product. What I need to do is use the select statement to join product.suburb, store.suburb and somehow get staff suburb along with store.

Thank you.

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: use excel, screen print, crop, and show us what you want

Comment: @Tito, no images... Formatted text is the way to go!

Comment: The expected output is meant to show suburb from product, suburb from store and the staff along with the suburb.

Comment: Please compose a title that captures your question, not yet another uselessly vague one that bypasses the check that is there for a reason. Please edit clarifications into your post, not comments. Please read & act on [mcve]. But @Tito Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. "and somehow get" is not clear. Please use enough words, phrases & sentences to say what you mean in detail. Almost certainly this is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you need below

```
select t1.*,t2.* from
   (
    SELECT Product.productNo, Product.suburb, Store.suburb

    FROM Product
    INNER JOIN Store ON Product.storeNo = Store.StoreNo
    INNER JOIN Staff ON Product.staffNo = Staff.staffNo AND Store.storeNo = Staff.storeNo
)t1
join 
(SELECT Store.suburb
        FROM Store join Staff
        on Staff.storeNo = Store.storeNo
       ) t2 on t1.suburb=t2.suburb
```

Comment: There's no need for a nested query.